# ASP.NET MVC Razor dynamic load new textbox and dropdownlist in a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

i´m just testing ASP.NET MVC Razor for one of my projects and i run in a problem i have no solution for at moment. Maybe someone can help me.
I have a page with two input elements. A textBox and a DropdownList which is filled by a model table. Now i want the possibility to clone that fields so the user can make more inputs then just one line.
I looked for different ways but i always loose cause of the DropDownList. I´m not so fit in js so maybe i missed a good way there to bind the dropdownlist.
Here is my page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SelectionList";
}
<h1>Search for Models</h1>
<h2>Search Request</h2>
<fieldset>
<legend>Here you can Search for all accessible TumorModels</legend>
@using(Html.BeginForm("SearchTumorModel","Search",FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "searchForm"}))
{
    <table id="formTable"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Specification</th>
                <th>Input</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.TextBox("Search") in</td>
                <td> @Html.DropDownList("SelectionList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.SelectionList) </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <p> <button name="button" value="add" class="formbutton" >Add one more search field</button></p>
    <p> 
        <button name="button" value="search" class="formbutton" >Search</button>
        <button name="button" value="clear" class="formbutton" >Clear</button>
    </p>
}
</fieldset>
```

Thanks for help :)

Update: Solves with:

```
@model Tumormodelle.Models.SearchModel
<table>
  @for (int i = 0; i < (int) Model.SearchCount ;i++ )
{  <tr>
    <th>@if(i > 0){<select name="ConnectorList" id="ConnectorList">
        <option value="AND" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i-1).Equals("AND") ?"selected":"")>AND</option>
        <option value="OR" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i-1).Equals("OR") ?"selected":"") >OR</option> 
         <option value="NAND" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i-1).Equals("NAND") ?"selected":"") >NAND</option>
         <option value="NOR" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i-1).Equals("NOR") ?"selected":"") >NOR</option>
                   </select>}</th>
 <th> <input name="SearchInput" id="SearchInput" type="text" value="@(Model.SearchList.ElementAt(i) as String)" /></th>
<th><select name="SelectionList" id="SelectionList">
@for (int j = 0; j < Model.SelectedList.Count(); j++)
{<option value="@j" @(Model.Selection.ElementAt(i).Equals(j) ?"selected":"")> @(Model.SelectedList.ElementAt(j).Name as String)</option> 
}    </select> 
</th></tr>}

</table><p> <button name="button" value="add" class="formbutton" >Add one more search field</button> <button name="button" value="sub" class="formbutton" >Remove one search field</button></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Steven Sanderson wrote an [`excellent article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) explaining step by step how to achieve this. The idea is to have a controller action that will return a partial view containing the new record and which will be invoked using an AJAX call when the user decides to add a new row. Also it uses a custom helper called `Html.BeginCollectionItem` which generates non-sequential indexes (Guids) for the names of the input fields so that the [`standard naming convention`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) is being respected when adding/deleting rows.